# Must logging out of CV really require 4 clicks?

Tags: support, user-interface, login

Does the new site design *really* need four steps to log out of CV?

1. Click the StackExchange image top left.
2. Click the StackExchange image top left, but this time featuring a down arrow/triangle.
3. Navigate the menu opened by clicking in step 2.
4. Click the Log Out button

Is there a more user-friendly way to log out?

Comment: Step #2 as listed here will probably stop working after the new design of the top bar will roll out on http://stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you click the icon at the top right (the one that looks like a hamburger), a list drops down.  That list includes a link to log out.  That way will only take you two steps.

[image]

Comment: +1 So why must logging out of CV require two clicks? ;)

Comment: @IWS, because the site designers said so.

Comment: Fair enough https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Intervention